# Redirect certain urls based on location

Tags: javascript, url, geolocation, server-side-includes

I have a number of links to Amazon UK on my (Joomla 3.4) website - these are links to buy books. They are basically 'Buy Now' buttons that take the user to the relevant Amazon UK item page (e.g www.amazon.co.uk/myBook) - html code below

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="http://www.amazon.co.uk/myBook...">Buy</a>
```

What I would like to do is re-direct US visitors to www.amazon.com

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="http://www.amazon.com/myBook...">Buy</a>
```

I know I could just add another button ('Buy US') but I only want one button per page.

I though I could perhaps either modify the `.htaccess` file, or add some javascript code so that vititors from the us will be taken to `.com` and not `.co.uk`?

I was looking at the [geoPlugin](http://www.geoplugin.com/) and [IP2Location](http://www.ip2location.com/free/visitor-redirection#source-codes) - can either or these be used to achieve this?

Perhaps I could modify the IP2Location code (below) somehow?

```
<?php
require_once 'IP2Location.php';

$loc = new IP2Location('databases/IP-COUNTRY.BIN', IP2Location::FILE_IO);
$record = $loc->lookup($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], IP2Location::ALL);

if($record == 'US') {
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: http://amazon.com');
    exit;
}
?>
```

Not sure how I can user server side includes to achievce this?

Any help or direction is appreciated, I'm keen to learn by myself.

Comment: You're probably going to need to change your content so the `<a href` points to the .com site. Because once someone clicks on the `.co.uk` site, it's completely out of your hands.

Comment: There's an HTML proxy that you can setup to dynamically change the content of your pages, but the problem is the content, not htaccess. If I click on a link for google.com, my browser goes straight to google.com, doesn't care about your htaccess file at all.

Comment: A few lines if JavaScript,  on your page, will do what you want, but close this as not really an Apache thing, unless you go down the dynamic page route.

Comment: Apache HTTPD supports [SSI (Server Side Includes)](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html), but nothing to do with rewrites, and what you want can be done in JS, again nothing to do with rewriting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit /index.php in Joomla to as below:

```
$output = ob_get_clean();

require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/IP2Location.php';

$db = new \IP2Location\Database('./databases/IP-COUNTRY-SAMPLE.BIN');
$records = $db->lookup($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

if($records['countryCode'] == 'US'){
      echo str_replace('www.amazon.co.uk', 'www.amazon.com', $output);
}
else{
      echo $output;
}
```